# Colorings of Topological Partitions (Path adjacency)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.

DEFINITIONS:

Define a **topological partition of $X$ into connected sets** to be a collection of pairwise disjoint open connected sets $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that $\bigcup_{i\in I} \mathrm{cl}(U_i)=X$.

Define $U,V\in\tau$ to be **adjacent** if there exists an $x\in U$ and a $y\in V$ such that there exists a path $\phi:[0,1]\to\mathrm{cl}(U)\cup\mathrm{cl}(V)$ from $x$ to $y$. Denote "$U$ and $V$ are adjacent" by $U\leftrightarrow V$.

Call a topological partition of $X$ into connected sets, $\mathcal{P}$, **$k$-colorable** if there exists a function $c:\mathcal{P}\to\{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that $c(U)\ne c(V)$ whenever $U\leftrightarrow V$ and $U\ne V$.

QUESTION:

What is the minimum $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ such that every topological partition into connected sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology is $k$-colorable?

NOTE: If the Four Color Theorem for maps in the plane is cited, please state the conditions for that theorem and why they are satisfied. The conditions I have seen for that theorem concern the boundaries of regions whereas no restrictions on boundaries are explicitly stated here.

Comment: @bof thank you! got /cap and /cup confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb N$ let
$$U_n=\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta):r\gt0,\ \frac{2\pi}{n+1}\lt\theta\lt\frac{2\pi}n\}.$$
Then (if I understand the definitions) $\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a partition of $\mathbb R^2$ into open connected sets which are pairwise adjacent, showing that the answer to your question is $k=\infty$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This definition of adjacency is too broad because it permits crossings at corners.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at my second attempt to define adjacency [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183070/colorings-of-topological-partitions-color-boundedness).