# Colorings of Topological Partitions (color-boundedness)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.

DEFINITIONS:

Define a **topological partition of $X$ into connected sets** to be a collection of pairwise disjoint open connected sets $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that $\bigcup_{i\in I} \mathrm{cl}(U_i)=X$.

Define $U,V\in\tau$ to be **adjacent** if there is a homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ into $\delta U\cap \delta V$. Denote "$U$ and $V$ are adjacent" by $U\leftrightarrow V$.

Call a topological partition of $X$ into connected sets, $\mathcal{P}$, **$k$-colorable** if there exists a function $c:\mathcal{P}\to\{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that $c(U)\ne c(V)$ whenever $U\leftrightarrow V$ and $U\ne V$.

Call a coarser topology, $\tau'$, **$k$-color bounded** if every topological partition of $X$ into connected sets that is a subset of $\tau'$ is $k$-colorable. and call $\tau'$ **maximally $k$-color bounded** if no $k$-color bounded sub-topology of $\tau$ contains $\tau'$ as a proper subset.

QUESTION:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B})$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the usual (metric) topology. Describe for an arbitrary $k\in\mathbb{N}$ a maximally $k$-color bounded topology.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182099/can-somebody-turn-this-into-a-shorter-question?lq=1) for the story behind this question.

Comment: Let's see. If for $n\in\mathbb Z$ we define$$U_n=\{(x,y):x\gt0,\ \frac1x\sin\frac1x+n\lt y\lt\frac1x\sin\frac1x+n+1\},$$$$V_n=\{(x,y):x\lt0,\ \frac1x\sin\frac1x+n\lt y\lt\frac1x\sin\frac1x+n+1,$$then (with respect to the usual topology) $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}U_n\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}V_n$ is a partition of $\mathbb R^2$ into open connected sets which are pairwise adjacent, isn't it?

Comment: @bof I think this is 2-color bounded. I think it is not maximal, though. Could one not add $\{(x,y):0<x<1\}$ to the basis and still have a 2-color bounded topology?

Comment: @bof I misread your example. But now I don't think $\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\cup\{V_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ covers $\mathbb{R}^2$, so does not generate a topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Is the topology formed by the sets of the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}$ with the product of $\mathbb{R}$ ($\{U\times\mathbb{R}:U \text{ open in } \mathbb{R}\}$) maximally $k$-colorable?

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer your question about topologies. The only point of my comment was that your new definition of adjacency still allows many disjoint open regions to be mutually adjacent, or so it seems to me.

Comment: @bof Oh, I see. Yes, this is the definition of adjacent I was using in [the original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182099/can-somebody-turn-this-into-a-shorter-question?lq=1) that is not strict enough to get a restriction on colorings. The Four Color Theorem results from restricting attention to a very narrow class of partitions called "plane maps". So this question aims to find a broader class of partitions than plane maps but smaller class than all partitions so that coloring can be used to say something about the structure of the space.